# In order to catch BOOT_COMPLETED, is it enough just to register the BroadcastReceiver in the `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

In order to catch `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` events, is it enough just to register the `BroadcastReceiver` in the `AndroidManifest.xml`? like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.myDomain.myApp"
          android:installLocation="internalOnly">
    <!-- ... stuff ... -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <!-- ... stuff ... -->
    <application ...>
        <!-- ... stuff ... -->
        <receiver android:name=".bgServices.MyBootBroadcastReceiver">
        </receiver>
        <!-- ... stuff ... -->
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
package com.myDomain.myApp.bgServices;

// imports ...

public class MyBootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("my-log", "MyBootBroadcastReceiver.onReceive()");
        Toast.makeText(context, "YEAY!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
    }
}
```

I'm asking because I'm sending:

`adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -n com.myDomain.myApp/.bgServices.MyBootBroadcastReceiver`

But nothing happens.

(and I run the app, not just pushing it to the device)

Comment: @jankigadhiya, see the last line in my post: "(and I run the app, not just pushing it to the device)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following `IntentFilter`s to your `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
<receiver android:name=".bgServices.MyBootBroadcastReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Although `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` should be enough, it seems some devices require `android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON` also.

For more information, you should take a look at the [developer's guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) on `Intent`s and `IntentFilter`s.

Answer (score 1):

No That is not. You did not specified the component which will receive the ACTION `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`. So you need to add intent-filter to your receiver

You should do it like below.

```
<receiver android:name=".bgServices.MyBootBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```